# php preg_match to validate and parse entry line

Tags: php, preg-match

I am not very good with parsing via regex and am trying to learn it for a project I am working on that requires lots of validation/parsing.

An entry line is in one of two formats:

1 - 50 of 4999 Entries xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

28 Entries

[1 above:  validate number, '-', number, 'of', number, text = Entries

[2 above:  validate number, text = Entries

I would like to validate and parse the entries so that the numeric part (eg. 4999, 28) is in the same array element (say $n_arr[3] for example).

Here is a try that almost works but does parse the elements differently depending on the input format.

```
    $m = preg_match("/(((.*?)-(.*?)of(.*?))|(.*?))Entries/", $t4, $n_arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like:

```
'/(?:(\d+) - (\d+) of )?(\d+) Entries/'
```

The 28 or 4999 will be in the 3rd capture group ($n_arr[3])